# What does the acronym LCA mean in relation to battery cranking amps?

Tags: batteries

I am attempting to compare some lithium iron phosphate batteries to their standard lead-acid counterparts.  One metric used is the CCA (cold cranking amps) value.  However, these lithium batteries use an acronym "LCA" instead... for example "480 LCA" which is an unknown term to me.  I assume CA = Cranking Amps but I can't figure out the "L".

I'm unfamiliar with the term LCA and can't seem to find it on google, except to mean "Lifecycle Analysis" which is not applicable in this case.

Can anyone tell me what this term means, and how it compares to CCA of standard lead-acid batteries?

Answer (score 3):

It stands for "Lithium Cranking Amperes":

[image]

According to [Battery University](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_measure_cca_cold_cranking_amp) the CCA measuring method is prescribed by a Society of Automotive Engineers standard as so:

> SAE J537 specifies that a battery with a CCA reading of 500A can
>   deliver 500A at -18ºC (0ºF) for 30 seconds without dropping below 7.2
>   volts

"LCA" is measured differently, and there may not be a standard for it yet. Some vendors list the amperes that can be supplied for a set period of time (15 or 30 seconds) without damage to the battery. You may have to contact the battery manufacturer to find the actual test conditions. Be sure to ask about temperature, if that's important to you.

.

Comment: Yes I noticed that the Lithium batteries I was comparing are rated only as low as 40 degrees F.  Thus CCA would not apply as they aren't rated at 0 degrees.